# Script for printing multiple PDFs on a single page

Tags: windows, matlab, pdf, cmd, acrobat

I have generated figures from an analysis as PDFs for each one of my 112 experiments (an experiment is a session that consists of 8 sub-sessions; there are 14 experiments total). The figure PDFs for each experiment are stored in a separate folder, and for each experiment, I have between 1 and 9 figure PDFs.

To summarize the results of an experiment, I would like to have all the figures for an experiment appear on a one-page PDF. To accomplish this, I have been:

1. generating the figures in MATLAB;
2. using MATLAB code to save each figure to a separate PDF (organized by folder, so there are 112 folders);
3. using [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to combine figure PDFs for an experiment into a single up-to-9-page PDF with a batch script;
4. and then printing the resultant PDF to another PDF using the "multiple" page layout option with 9 pages/sheet, horizontal page order, page borders printed, and sheets oriented in landscape (even if there are fewer than 9 figure PDFs for an experiment, I still use the 9 pages/sheet option).

For each experiment, I generate my figures, and print them to PDFs using the following MATLAB code:

```
figDir = ['G:\Figures\' session '\' sub_session '\'];
for i = 1:num_figs
    figure(i)
    fig = gcf;
    fig.PaperPositionMode = 'auto';
    fig_pos = fig.PaperPosition;
    fig.PaperSize = [fig_pos(3) fig_pos(4)];

    print([figDir 'fig' num2str(i)], '-dpdf')
end
```

The MATLAB code for step 3 is given here:

```
myDir = 'G:\Figures';

sessions = dir(myDir);
sessions(1:2) = []; % to get rid of . and ..

for i = 1:length(sessions)
    sub_sessions = dir([myDir '\' sessions(i).name]);
    sub_sessions(1:2) = []; % to get rid of . and ..

    for j = 1:length(sub_sessions)
        cd([myDir '\' sessions(i).name '\' sub_sessions(j).name])
        eval(['!pdftk *.pdf cat output ' sessions(i).name '_' sub_sessions(j).name '.pdf'])
    end
end
```

The bottleneck for me is step 4 in my list, since I have to manually go through each experiment's combined PDF (result of step 3, which contains up to 9 pages) and manually choose the options to print with. Everything else runs in a matter of seconds, but all the pointing and clicking in the last step takes about 45 minutes to do. Is there any way this can be sped up with some sort of scripting?

I am using Windows 7 64-bit and have Adobe Acrobat X Pro.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that we're supposed to be here to help you with your code. Please can you post the script you have written so far and explain where and how you're having problems with it.

Comment: I added code samples, but just to be clear, I'm not having problems with my code. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to automate combining a multi-page PDF into a single PDF. I suspect there must be some application or script out there that can do this, but I can't seem to find an application and don't know how to write a script that can do this.

Comment: The code you've provided is not a batch file as per your included tag. To be clear, _you've confirmed that there are no problems with your code_, this site is therefore not appropriate for your type of question.

Comment: The string in the `eval` command is a Windows command line script that is executed by `cmd`. It’s not actually a batch file, but what difference does it make whether it’s its own file or a line in my MATLAB code? I don’t do much Windows shell scripting, so maybe the word “batch” is a misnomer. Feel free to correct me if I’m wrong. Also, I’ve been here long enough to know that this question *is* most definitely appropriate for this site. Please read it carefully. If you don’t want to answer, you’re welcome not to.

Comment: If you've posted Matlab code then you should use the matlab tag, if you are using the Windows command line, then you sholud use the cmd tag. Please read carefully, this site provides a platform for developers to assist others in fixing issues with their code. You have told use that you don't have a problem with your code; please consider another site such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/about) instead. _**I have updated your tags to assist**_.